# Disable Facebook Pixel code on specific button click events

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

Having trouble with Pixel code. I have button click event which fetches data on ajax calls. The problem is that facebook button click event `SubscribedButtonClick` is also triggered which interferes with the ajax call failing any response from the server.

I have looked into their API but did not get anything helpful. Is there any setting or code which can help to bypass this button click event or disable the `SubscribedButtonClick` call on specific button clicks?

Answer (score 17):

It is possible to disable automatic `SubscribedButtonClick` and `MicroData` tracking events:

```
fbq('set', 'autoConfig', false, 'FB_PIXEL_ID')
```

Comment: Here's a link to the docs for this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/advanced/#automatic-configuration